# Break For loop and enter results into different table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Taking results from API and sorting into different fileds, problem is that i have 20 columns returned from API and i want 2 different tables with 10 results each.

```
j = 3
For Each result In JSON.Item("results")

Cells(20, j) = result.Item("param_1")
Cells(21, j) = result.Item("param_2")
Cells(22, j) = result.Item("param_3")
Cells(23, j) = result.Item("param_4")
i = 0

For Each t In result.Item("param_5")
    If i > 0 Then
        Cells(24, j) = Cells(24, j) & ", " & t
    Else
        Cells(24, j) = t
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
Cells(25, j) = result.Item("param_6")
Cells(26, j) = result.Item("param_7")
j = j + 1
Next
```

This is work well for every 20 columns, problem is when i add this part of code under first part, obviously its not works well in first table i get 10 results but in next table i have only one entry.

```
If j >= 13 Then
j = 3

Cells(33, j) = result.Item("param_1")
Cells(34, j) = result.Item("param_2")
Cells(35, j) = result.Item("param_3")
Cells(36, j) = result.Item("param_4")
i = 0
For Each t In result.Item("param_5")
    If i > 0 Then
        Cells(37, j) = Cells(37, j) & ", " & t
    Else
        Cells(37, j) = t
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
Cells(38, j) = result.Item("param_6")
Cells(39, j) = result.Item("param_7")
```

Comment: I suggest you show some actual data before and after. It doesn't have to be your own data -- just something simple to demonstrate. Focus on demonstrating what you want and where it's going wrong. If you do this, I'm sure you'll get help.

Comment: I am guessing a bit here as I don't find the question clear but my guess is you are expecting 'j' to be incremented but you don't have a 'j' in a 2nd 'for/next' loop as you do in your first block of code. 

Apart from that though....this should be straight forward to debug so I will describe some basic debugging... Stick a break in (ie click to the left of the edit window) near where you see what is not working. Hit f5 to start and let the macro get to the break point and  then hit 'f8' to move step by step to observe the output and identify where it is going wrong.

Comment: Your question is not clear because you are requesting 2 columns of then values each and later you are exposing that your code is working ok for 20 columns. Could you upload some screenshots with your input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks @dra_red i have debugged it. Thing is in **If j >= 13 Then** under added **n = 3** and other for loop is entering into second table.

Comment: Good to hear you sorted it Milenko. Cheers